# Create binary matrix from occurence data in R

Tags: r, statistics, binary-data

I am trying to create a binary occurrence matrix for multiple individuals across a time series of survey occasions.  The source data is a dataframe that contains an individual ID field and an occasion number field corresponding to a positive occurrence for that individual.  I need to retain the individual ID in the output matrix.  Note that individuals who had positive occurrences on multiple occasions occur in the source dataset >1 times.  I tried adapting code from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981677/how-to-create-a-binary-matrix-of-inventory-per-row-r), but I cannot get it to work.

Here is a snippet of example source data and the desired matrix:

SOURCE:

```
ID1   1
ID1   3
ID1   7
ID2   4
ID3   2
ID3   6
ID4   8
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID1   10100010
ID2   00010000
ID3   01000100
ID4   00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

I've given your data names:

```
names(dat) <- c("id", "num")
```

To sort this out, I made a quick function which makes a vector of length 8 and fills in the appropriate spots with ones.

```
rep8 <- function(x){
  zeroes <- rep(0, 8)
  zeroes[x] <- 1
  zeroes
}
```

Then apply this function to each id and `rbind` them into a matrix

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(dat$num, dat$id, rep8))

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
ID1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
ID2    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
ID3    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
ID4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian.  The function you provided worked very well.  Much appreaciated!